# weird own iterator behviour compared to list from STL

Tags: c++, stl

Hi I have implemented my own list and iterator.

my main code is:

```
List<int> myList;
myList.push_back(1);
myList.push_back(2);
myList.push_back(3);

cout << std::string(30, '-') << endl;
//this shows 1 2
for(List<int>::iterator it = myList.begin() ; it != myList.end() ; ++it){
    cout << *it << " ";
}
cout << endl;

//The same using stl shows 1 2 3 !!!???
list<int> myListSTL;
myListSTL.push_back(1);
myListSTL.push_back(2);
myListSTL.push_back(3);
cout << std::string(30, '-') << endl;
for(list<int>::iterator it = myListSTL.begin() ; it != myListSTL.end() ; ++it){
    cout << *it << " ";
}
cout << endl;
```

I implemented all methods for my own iterator.
For my own implementation output is : 1 2
For list from STL implementation output is : 1 2 3

1)My begin() method:

```
template<class T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::begin(){
    return iterator(head);
}
```

2)My end() method:

```
  template<class T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::end(){
    Node * current = head;
    while(current->next)
        current = current->next;
    return iterator(current);
}
```

3)overloaded operator !=

```
template<class T>
const bool List<T>::iterator::operator!=(const iterator & it){  
    return (node != it.node);
}
```

4)overloaded preincrement operator:

```
template<class T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::iterator::operator++(){
    if(node->next){
        node = node->next;      
    }
    return iterator(node);
}
```

I analyse this whole day and i dont have idea what can i did wrong.
Thak You in advance for any kind of help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `end` method should return an iterator **past the end** of your list (not an iterator to the last element), so typically:

```
template<class T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::end(){
    Node * current = head;
    while(current->next)
        current = current->next;
    return iterator(current);
}
```

Should simply become this:

```
template<class T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::end(){
    return iterator(0);
}
```

And then remove the check in `operator++` so that `++it` will get you an `iterator(0)` if you are on the last element (which is what you want):

```
template<class T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::iterator::operator++(){
    node = node->next;      
    return iterator(node);
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU SOLUTION BEST!! I JUST DIDNT KNOW STL IDEA ABOUT POINTING AFTER LAST ELEMENT!!

Answer (score 0):

Your `end` iterator needs to point to something beyond the last element of the data to be consistent with STL's concept of `end` (so currently you're one short).

Comment: Thank You i got idea, but if i return last->next this is NULL, so how i can compare with ++it with this NULL ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `end` function should return iterator for one past the end item in your list. Currently it returns last item so you dont see all the list items.

The proper fix for your iterator should rely on the implementation of your node class. For example gcc version looks as follows:

```
  iterator
  end() _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
  { return iterator(&this->_M_impl._M_node); }
```